# C struct timeval timersub() negative value to positive

Tags: c, time, timer

I'm using `timersub(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b, struct timeval *res)` to make operation on time.
And what I would to do is, substract a higher value to a lower value and get the difference of time which is in the negative.

For example :

```
int             main()
{
  struct timeval        left_operand;
  struct timeval        right_operand;
  struct timeval        res;

  left_operand.tv_sec = 0;
  left_operand.tv_usec = 0;
  right_operand.tv_sec = 0;
  right_operand.tv_usec = 1;
  timersub(&left_operand, &right_operand, &res);
  printf("RES : Secondes : %ld\nMicroseconds: %ld\n\n", res.tv_sec, res.tv_usec);
  return 0;
 }
```

The output is :
`RES : Secondes : -1 Microseconds: 999999`

What I would like to have is : `RES : Secondes : 0 Microseconds: 1`

Does someone have any idea of the trick ? I'd like to store the result in a struct timeval too.

Comment: Why don't you just flip the operands? Then you'd get a positive difference.

Comment: Because I actually do this operation in a loop, and values become negatives during the execution, so I must keep this order in the operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check which time value is bigger to determine which order to provide the operands:

```
if (left_operand.tv_sec > right_operand.tv_sec)
    timersub(&left_operand, &right_operand, &res);
else if (left_operand.tv_sec < right_operand.tv_sec)
    timersub(&right_operand, &left_operand, &res);
else  // left_operand.tv_sec == right_operand.tv_sec
{
    if (left_operand.tv_usec >= right_operand.tv_usec)
        timersub(&left_operand, &right_operand, &res);
    else
        timersub(&right_operand, &left_operand, &res);
}
```